SharePoint Online - How to update image size when replacing an image
We are developing a website that will have 200+ pages where an image may need to be updated periodically. The original image was 946px x 111px and the current version is more square at 748px x 605px. Using the same image name, we replaced the image expecting to see the updated image on the pages. Instead it displays as a narrow strip on the page (the dimensions of the original image) and when we click on the image, it appears as the correct size.
Image as displayed on web page:
Image with correct demensions:
We deleted the image from the library and uploaded it again with the same name to replace the image on the web pages but the original dimensions remain. We refreshed our pages, cleared cache in browsers, and had new users view the pages but still the original dimensions remain. How can we get the image to display correctly on the SharePoint modern page?
